# Multiple node apps with NGINX in sub-directories

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I currently have a digital ocean droplet connected to a domain. On the server, I'm running NGINX and trying to reverse proxy multiple node apps to it. Currently, my root directory has one node express app, at location / .

I'm trying to connect another node express application, to another sub directory. Here's the nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name servername.com;

    # my root app
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # new app
    location ~^ /newapp {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the new app is trying to serve files out of /newapp, which is breaking. I'm thinking it's probably something in my app.js file to play around with Express in the new app, to set the base directory as /newapp/ - to serve both static files and routes from there. Any ideas on how to do this?

In the newapp, I'm serving static files as such:

```
// Serve files out of ./public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and have route files as:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
```

with index routing file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Get index page
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        index : 'active'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't use regexp location if you no need it. Use simple location. And about your question - put `/` at the end of proxy_pass URI. Nginx will rewrite /newapp/xxx to /xxx and vice versa (for http redirects, for example). But (!) will not rewrite links in HTML body.

```
location /newapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6002/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue: Multiple node apps with NGINX in sub-directories. I used the code below. It is working fine.

```
    location /smtest { 
    rewrite ^/smtest/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/;
}
```